# SharePoint online and Azure graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have few scenarios needs to be executed in an intranet. Basically,i have a placeholder in an share point page where

a. I need to expand a group (consider you are on team page and I need to display people in that AD group)
b. There is define email id where all the events goes to. (ex: training..consider I have learn@mycompany.com) I need to read these events and display them in intranet
c. I need to read users events and display them.

I have been reading and seems graph api can solve my problem but not sure how to start. I see that I can get tokens using adal but it seems it doesn't work on IE becoz of cookie issue.

Is there anyone who can guide me as how auth can happen without exposing the token i uRL and asking user to login again?

Answer (score 0):

> > a. I need to expand a group (consider you are on team page and I need to display people in that AD group)

The Microsoft graph should work for get the members for the specific group. (refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members))

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/members
```

> > b.There is define email id where all the events goes to. (ex: training..consider I have learn@mycompany.com) I need to read these events and display them in intranet

As far as I know, the SharePoint group calendar already enable we to see the multiple calendars at the same time([SharePoint group calendar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-Group-Calendar-7f559b2e-1f90-49b4-a0fe-2d235994945e)).

> > c. I need to read users events and display them.

The Microsoft also support to get the events. (refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_events))

```
GET /me/events
GET /users/<id | userPrincipalName>/events

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
```

> > Is there anyone who can guide me as how auth can happen without exposing the token i uRL and asking user to login again?
> >     No. To access the retract resource via the REST, we need to use OAuth 2.0 to authentication which require the token.

In your scenario, we can develop an web service app using “Client Credentials Grant flow” which not require users to sign-in. This authentication flow is using the its own credentials to authenticate. Here are the main steps to achieve the goal for your reference:

1. Register an web app on Azure ad(refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization))
2. Develop an web service as the proxy for the event service using “client credentials grant flow”( refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx))
3. write the JavaScript to call the proxy to get the events data you wanted